# FileUpload component empty on AsyncPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, file-upload, updatepanel

I have an AJAX `UpdatePanel` and a `GridView` inside it. A `FileUpload` component outside the updatepanel.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="documentUpload" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="btnUploadDocumentDetails" runat="server" OnClick="btnUploadDocumentDetails_Click" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel_DocumentDetails" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnuploaddocumentdetails" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvDocuments" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On button click I have to upload the file on the server and update the `GridView` (gridview contains the list of all files).

**Problem:**

When I click on the button to upload the file, the `FileUpload` component gets empty (`HasFile` attribute returns `false`).

How can I resolve this issue to asynchronously update the `GridView`?

Comment: Your problem is that you are doing async postback. Regular straight file upload is not possible in this scenario. There are various workarounds though with iframes, flash, etc. Search for "asp.net async file upload"

Comment: Is it the `asp.net` component or I will have to get `Ajax tool kit`?

Comment: I am not aware of any asp.net built-in control for this. There is one in ajax control toolkit, and lots of others across the web. I would not advocate for any particular solotion though, as that was a long time since I've used any of them

Comment: @Shaharyar, there are both the asp.net Fileupload control and the ajax too. You can find examples for both, but as Andrei said you cannot use regular fileupload control inside updatepanel.

Comment: I am not using it inside the updatePanel, as you can see it is outside the panel.